# Cloudant add lucene index via curl

Tags: curl, lucene, cloudant

So having created an index function and tested it, it should be integrated to the database initialisation steps.
I currently have the following:

indexRequest.json

```
{
"indexes": {
    "mySearch": {
      "index": "function (doc) {
        index('default', doc.name);
        if (doc.description) {
          index('default', doc.description);
        }
      }"
    }
  }
}
```

Now I'm trying to send this file to cloudant via:

```
curl -X PUT https://$username:$password@$myurl.cloudant.com/myDatabase/_design/myTest  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @indexRequest.json
```

Which fails with

```
{"error":"conflict","reason":"Document update conflict."}
```

`myTest` already contains an index function, with a different name.
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When updating or deleting document in Cloudant, you must supply the new document body with the previous version's _rev token. The procedure is

1) read the existing document

```
curl -X PUT https://$username:$password@$myurl.cloudant.com/myDatabase/_design/myTest
```

This will give you the existing body. Modify the body to your specifications. Then

2) write the document back

```
curl -X PUT https://$username:$password@$myurl.cloudant.com/myDatabase/_design/myTest  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @indexRequest.json
```

where the original _id and _rev are in the json file.

You should then get back a confirmation:

```
{
    "ok":true,
    "id":"_design/myTest",
    "rev":"2-9176459034"
}
```

Here's the [Cloudant Docs on updating documents](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/document.html#update) and a more detailed write-up on [Design Document management](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/guides/design_document_management.html#design-document-management)